# Como resolver "Call to a member function prepare()"?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou encontrando o seguinte erro no *script* abaixo:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp\www\cursophp\orientacao_objeto\pdo_statement\usuarios.php on line 20

Código:

```
class Usuarios {

private $db;

public function _construct(){

    try{
        $this->$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=blog;host=localhost", "root", "");

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo " Falha na conexão: ".$e->getMessage();
    }

}

public function selecionar($id) {

    $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=:id");
    $sql->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $sql->execute();

    $array = array();
    if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
        $array = $sql->fetch();
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Esse nome parece errado: `_construct()` falta um underline ...

Answer (score 4):

O construtor de um classe no PHP deve ter como nome dois underlines seguidos da palavra `construct`. No seu código existe apenas um underline, **isso não invoca o construtor definido** mas o construtor padrão. Logo não incializa a propriedade `$db` com a instância do PDO.

Mude:

```
public function _construct(){
```

Para:

```
public function __construct(){
```

Comment: Agora deu certo. muito obrigado!